Validity of approximations in the derivation of sound waves from Newton's laws
In deriving the wave equation describing the displacement of air in the atmosphere usually some assumptions about the displacement function $\chi(x,t)$ are made. For example Feynman says:

Now in sound waves all changes are small so that $\rho_e$ is small, $\chi$ is small, and ∂$\chi$/∂x is also small.

I agree that $\chi$ is small, but what physically justifies ∂$\chi$/∂x being small?
More generally, is there any resource that explores in depth the topic of when approximations are valid in physics?
